# Python Turtle - Turtle Location

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make the turtle goto the floor if it is above a set of coordinates:

something like this:

```
floor = -323

if turtle above floor:
    turtle.goto(floor)
```

But I don't know how the `'if'` statement would work, as you can't simply put `'if turtle above floor'` Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your "floor" is at y=-323 you could probably do something like this:

```
floor = -323

if turtle.ycor() > floor:
     turtle.sety(floor)
```

You retrieve the turtles y coordinate with `turtle.ycor()`, check if its larger than `floor`, and if it is set the y coordinate equal to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the X coordinate of the turtles x, too, just so it doesn't respond with an error.

```
floor = -323
if turtle.ycor() > floor:
    turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), floor)
```

Comment: What error do you anticipate `sety()` throwing different from `goto()`?  Just curious.

Comment: I've had some weird things happen, so I use goto, and it is reliable. Might've been operator error though.